# Read JSON file from remote website

Tags: java, json

I am making a java program and I am looking for a way to check if theres a new version available I made an account on parse.com.
API: [CLICK](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#general)
I am working entirely on java and I am a bit new so keep it simple. 
I have created a class with the version number and if the version is beta now i need a way to get these 2 values into a int and a boolean and do the rest of the proccessing.
How do i take the values from parse.com class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simplest way, you could use the library available at [json.org](http://json.org) for java (download [here](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)) and use a code similar to:

```
URL url = new URL("http://my.domain.com/data.json");
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(url.openStream());
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

But of course you could use some other library that offers a bit more of flexibility like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

A small sample for gson and jackson can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314988/1001027) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525152/1001027) respectively.

For basic authentication you could use something like:

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("usr", "pass".toCharArray());
    }
});

Something related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496651/1001027) and [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html).

Also, HTTPClient is a great library for HTTP related stuff, please check it [here](http://hc.apache.org/) if you are willing to.

---

If you are using Maven you can add the following dependency for json.org:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Gson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Jackson (with major version 1, but 2 is already available, check at the website):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

For HTTP Client Version 4:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: +1 for gson, +1 for jackson, -1 for json.org. Net +1. Lucky you!

Comment: I keep getting an java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/NicksNoteVersion/xngGDAa1k3

any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this is due the basic authentication you need to provide, check my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the http requests using standard Java API. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java).

You can parse the response by using gson library. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly).