# How to deserialize a JSON file into an ArrayList with nested classes?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this Java class:

```
class A {
    private B b;

    class B {
        private String a;
        //getter + setter
    }    
}
```

This is the content of JSON file:

```
[{"b" : {"a": "Hello!"}},
 {"b" : {"a": "Hi!"}},
 {"b" : {"a": "Hello2!"}}]
```

I want to deserialize my JSON file into an `ArrayList<A>` with the nested class inside.
How can I do this?

Comment: Post some sample of JSON data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with Gson.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q18932252;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Q18932252 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String json = "[{\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hello!\"}}, {\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hi!\"}}, {\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hello2!\"}}]";
        Type listOfA = new TypeToken<List<A>>() {}.getType();
        Gson g = new Gson();
        ArrayList<A> result = g.fromJson(json, listOfA);
        System.out.println(result);


    }

}
```

With this result (I have added standard `toString` methods):

```
[A [b=B [a=Hello!]], A [b=B [a=Hi!]], A [b=B [a=Hello2!]]]
```

Since you are asking about a JSON file, ie a text file that contains a JSON string, please make reference to [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) question for loading a file into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post as per the information provided in the question this should solve your problem [Json parsing with Gson with data and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529664/json-parsing-with-gson-with-data-and-arrays)

Comment: This isn't the thing I was looking for, because I don't need to deserialize a json file with a array property inside  the class, but I need to deserialize a json array of the whole class which contains a nested class.

Answer (score 0):

Using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "[{\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hello!\"}}, {\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hi!\"}}, {\"b\" : {\"a\": \"Hello2!\"}}]";
A[] arrA = new A[0];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gson.fromJson(json, arrA.getClass())));
```