# Using JSON to retrieve and display images from Tumblr

Tags: java, android, json, image

so i'm completely clueless here on the subject of retrieving, displaying and such using an API.  I've already gotten a JSON URL with all the parameters setup and such but I don't know how to express this in an Android application. I used jsongen.com to format everything and parse the JSON into java objects but am clueless from that point on.

Java Code:

```
package com.android.tumblr.api;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
          ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tvImage);
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)
new URL("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/423147305605554176/EYnBh68.jpeg")
.getContent());
          image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

XML code  of the Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvImage" 
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML code of manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tumblr.api"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.tumblr.api.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. It is not clear from your original post what is it that you trying to solve. How to fire request to fetch JSON, how to handle retrieval of JSON or how to fetch actual images???

Comment: All of them as I am new to it

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement JSON parser and should consider implementing cache manager for better performance.

For the implementation of the Json parser you have a lot of alternatives but according to my experience - Gson and JsonParser are the best.

Gson provide you the ability to auto create json from java entity or java entity from the gson. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314813/json-gson-fromjson-java-objects) you can find a good example for gson parsing, and from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you can download the library.

A good open source cache manager you can find here - [bitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), [volley](http://yakivmospan.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/volley-cacheimageloader/), [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

If you don't want to add cache manager you can simply download the image and execute:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android) code that streaming image into bitmap

Comment: But that's my problem. How do I get the ImageView to recognize the image from a JSON link?

Comment: First of all you need to create a bitmap, into that bitmap you need to stream the image's bytes from the link( you can use the decoder from the last link I sent you), after you have the bitmap execute the two lines of code from above.

Comment: I edited my code and did what you said. Yet it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post your code in order for us to help you?

Comment: I did so. Please check it out :)

Comment: It's giving me an error : "Failed to install TumblrAPITest.apk on device 'emulator-5554!"

Comment: @Victor Strandmoe it isn't a problem in loading the image from link to ImageView, it's a problem that you can't install the apk on your emulator. This is a totally different thread. Check that your emulator's OS version is at least the minSdkVersion from your manifest or try to load it on a real device.

Comment: Well i know that isn't the problem because even when I try to run it o a physical device using an AppInstaller it doesn't open at all. I'm sure it's the code :/

Comment: It is something with the installation of the apk, try to go through your project configuration or recreate the project(New -> Android project).

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing wrong in my code? would you mind trying and running that and see if it works on your device(s)?

Comment: Yes the error that you wrote here is making it pretty clear, moreover, if you had something wrong with your code than you would had a better log to show me, something like NullPointerException, ClassCastException, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library for implementing REST client. And [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is good enough for displaying images from URL into ImageView