# Parsing json file throws stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, json

I have a very complex object which I so far I used to serialize it to xml via `@XmlRootElement` and worked perfectly well. Now I am writing REST and I need to serialize it to json. What happens is it throws `StackOverflowError` exception. What I wrote so far is that the reason could be bi-directional mapping, but this  is not the case with me I think. What could be the reason and how can I track if I miss  bi-directional mapping, the object is really complex and supported from many people for very long time, is there a simple way I can track this that I can't think of?
Thanks!

EDIT 
Here is stack trace:

```
StackOverflowError
    java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1902)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1769)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1477)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1150)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:840)
    net.sf.json.regexp.JdkRegexpMatcher.<init>(JdkRegexpMatcher.java:38)
    net.sf.json.regexp.JdkRegexpMatcher.<init>(JdkRegexpMatcher.java:31)
    net.sf.json.regexp.RegexpUtils.getMatcher(RegexpUtils.java:39)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.matches(JSONTokener.java:113)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:962)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:156)
    net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
    net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1006
```

Comment: Try catching the SOE in a debugger and looking at the stack trace. You should be able to track that back to what is causing it.

Comment: If you use intellij/eclipse, there are tools to help detect cyclical dependencies in your object model. Or use third party tools out there that you can search for on Google. Worst case, you can traverse your object hierarchy from your base object and track it yourself to see if there exists a cycle

Comment: Show us the first 2 dozen or so of the exception stack trace entries.

Answer (score 0):

You better post your object and the code that you use to deserialize it. Also, you can try doing it  with a different library:

Jackson( the more-more-or-less standard lib for that): http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

GSON: [JSON GSON.fromJson Java Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314813/json-gson-fromjson-java-objects)