# Parsing JsonArray With JsonObject

Tags: android, parsing, javaparser

I have some JSON with the following structure:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "product":{
                "product_id":"some",
                "price_id":"some",
                "price":"some",
                "title_fa":"some",
                "title_en":"Huawei Ascend Y300",
                "img":"some",
                "has_discount_from_price":"0",
                "discount_from_price":null,
                "type_discount_from_price":null,
                "has_discount_from_product":"0",
                "discount_from_product":null,
                "type_discount_from_product":null,
                "has_discount_from_category":"0",
                "discount_from_category":null,
                "type_discount_from_category":null,
                "has_discount_from_brand":"0",
                "discount_from_brand":null,
                "type_discount_from_brand":null,
                "weight":null,
                "features":[
                    {
                        "feature_value":"#000000",
                        "feature_id":"some",
                        "feature_title":"some"
                    },
                    {
                        "feature_value":"some",
                        "feature_id":"1652",
                        "feature_title":"some"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "number":1,
            "feature_id":"56491,56493",
            "price_inf":{
                "has_discount":0,
                "discount_type":0,
                "final_price":"400000",
                "value_discount":0
            },
            "cart_id":13
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the elements "product_id" and "price_id" with the following Java code:

```
try{
        JSONArray feedArray=response.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i=0;i<feedArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject feedObj=feedArray.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject pro=feedObj.getJSONObject("product");
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setPrice(pro.getDouble("price_id"));
            product.setTitle_fa(pro.getString("price_id"));}}
```

but i see product not found error.what is wrong in my parser?

Comment: your json seems to be invalid

Comment: `debug` your code and see if `feedArray` is coming firstly. @KaranMer it think i was formatting error, `{}` paranthese missing only

Comment: Your JSON is invalid because top level element in JSON cannot have any name. It should be a unnamed JSON array `[..]` or object `{..}`.

Comment: can u show us the log file ? and json exception found or something

Comment: You need to get the product id and price like below

Comment: @Tasos he has just validated now. Check the edit history.

Comment: @ Malwinde -- Yeah i know i was wrong, the json is fine, i checked it here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON is valid. So no worries there.
Now regarding your problem, because you haven't posted the logs so I can't tell what the exact problem is. But using this code snippet you can get the desired values.

```
 try {
      JSONArray itemsJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
      for (int i = 0; i < itemsJsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject itemJsonObject = itemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject productObject = itemJsonObject.getJSONObject("product");
            String productId = productObject.getString("product_id");
            String priceId = productObject.getString("price_id");
      }

 } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate and create Pojo for your json [here](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

use

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(this.json, Data.class);
```

follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314988/5202007

By the way your JSON is invalid .

Comment: Why do you say that the json is invalid?

Comment: @hrskrs has validated the json now. please check in edit history.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a json object from your response not json array you need to make following changes

```
JSONObject temp =new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray feedArray=temp.getJSONArray("items");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting response string to `JSONObject` first

```
try{
JSONObject temp =new JSONObject(responseString); // response is a string
JSONArray feedArray=.getJSONArray("items");
      ....
  }
```

You may try to use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library for parsing a JSON string. Here's an example how to use GSON,

```
    Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
 MyType target = new MyType();
 String json = gson.toJson(target); // serializes target to Json
 MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```