# Gson.fromJSON returns 0 and null

Tags: java, json, gson

EDIT: My bad, I was creating a List of wrong object.

---

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON in Java that I can see correctly.
But using Gson.fromJson(), all attributes become 0 or null.

**Group.java**

```
public class Group extends Board {

    private String created_on;
    private ArrayList<GroupMember> members;
    private ArrayList<GroupChat> chat;
    private ArrayList<GroupInvite> invites;
    private int members_num;

    public Group(int id,
                 String name,
                 ArrayList<Post> posts,
                 int posts_num,
                 String created_on,
                 ArrayList<GroupMember> members,
                 ArrayList<GroupChat> chat,
                 ArrayList<GroupInvite> invites,
                 int members_num) {
        super(id, name, "group", posts, posts_num);
        this.members = members;
        this.chat = chat;
        this.invites = invites;
        this.members_num = members_num;
        this.created_on = created_on;
    }

    public int getId(){ return super.getBoardId(); }
    public String getName(){ return super.getName(); }
    public String getCreatedOn(){ return created_on; }
    public int getPostsNum(){ return super.getPostsNum(); }
    public ArrayList<Post> getPosts(){ return super.getPosts(); }
    public ArrayList<GroupMember> getMembers(){ return members; }
    public ArrayList<GroupInvite> getInvites(){ return invites; }

}
```

Here I'm trying to parse JSON

**GroupsRequests.java**

```
public ObservableList<Group> getUserGroups() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8000/groups/"))
                .setHeader("authorization", Auth.getInstance().getToken())
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = ApiClient.getInstance().getHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonOutput = response.body();
        System.out.println(response.body());

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Group>>(){}.getType();
        List<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
        list = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
        ObservableList<Group> groups = FXCollections.observableList(list);

        return groups;
    }
```

I can correctly print my `jsonOutput` and see my JSON output:

```
[
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":11,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:34:20",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:34:20",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":11,
         "name":"asd",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:34:20",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":12,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:46:43",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:46:43",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":12,
         "name":"test",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:46:43",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":13,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:49:07",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:49:07",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":13,
         "name":"f",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:49:07",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":14,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:50:39",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:50:39",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":14,
         "name":"nuovo",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:50:39",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":15,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:51:18",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:51:18",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":15,
         "name":"ggg",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:51:18",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":16,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:51:47",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:51:47",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":16,
         "name":"ff",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:51:47",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":17,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:53:46",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:53:46",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":17,
         "name":"dded",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:53:46",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":18,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:57:07",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:57:07",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":18,
         "name":"dedddd",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:57:07",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":19,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:58:02",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:58:02",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":19,
         "name":"sdas",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:58:02",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":20,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T14:58:48",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T14:58:48",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":20,
         "name":"slowmo",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T14:58:48",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":21,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T15:00:47",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T15:00:47",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":21,
         "name":"miogruppo",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T15:00:47",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":22,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T15:02:18",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T15:02:18",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":22,
         "name":"f",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T15:02:18",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":23,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T15:45:34",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T15:45:34",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":23,
         "name":"ohgno",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T15:45:34",
         "members_num":1
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":"AnvediFratello",
      "group_id":24,
      "join_date":"2020-08-31T15:45:36",
      "last_chat_read":"2020-08-31T15:45:36",
      "is_owner":true,
      "user":{
         "id":"AnvediFratello",
         "display_name":null,
         "registered_on":"2020-08-29T11:14:36"
      },
      "group":{
         "id":24,
         "name":"ohgno",
         "type":"group",
         "created_on":"2020-08-31T15:45:36",
         "members_num":1
      }
   }
]
```

but when i'ts converted in Gson

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Group>>(){}.getType();
List<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
list = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

Each field of `Group` in `list` is 0 or null, so I can't use this list, why?

Comment: Hi, Wellcome to SO, please read this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314813/json-gson-fromjson-java-objects

Answer (score 0):

#### No deserializing way

First of all, the class `Group` have neither no-args-constructor nor `InstanceCreator` defined.
GSON can not correctly instantiate the `Group`, so it uses the `UnsafeAllocator`, which allocates the empty instance.
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645370/9978153))

#### Mismatching DTO

Then, even the GSON succeeds the instantiating the instance, your incoming JSON has no fields in common with `Group` class. The `Group` class has fields named

`boardId`, `chat`, `created_on`, `invites`, `members`, `members_num`, `name`, `posts`, `postsNum`

but incoming JSON obkects have fields named

`group`, `group_id`, `is_owner`, `join_date`, `last_chat_read`, `user`, `user_id`

Then, the GSON foes not find any matches in names, then all fields of `Group` are `null` or `0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you think your data is a list of groups. But it isn't!
Your data is a list of objects that each have a group.

if you replace this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Group>>(){}.getType();
List<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
list = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

by this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<GroupWrapper>>(){}.getType();
List<GroupWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

using a class similar to this:

```
class GroupWrapper {
    Group group;
}
```

then you will have values inside your groups.

If you only want a List then you can do something like this:

```
List<Group> groupList = list.stream()
            .map(groupWrapper -> groupWrapper.group)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```